# mysqli_num_rows shows 1 row found, but mysqli_fetch_assoc returns empty fields when echo

Tags: php, mysqli

I have the following snippet of code. When I check how many rows the results array has, it prints out 1. But when I try to access the data within (firstname, lastname, username, etc.) it prints nothing out.

```
$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['username']);
$password = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['password']);

$password = md5($password);
$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'";
$results = mysqli_query($db, $query);

if (mysqli_num_rows($results) == 1) {
    $session_user = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

    $_SESSION['firstname'] = $session_user['firstname'];
    $_SESSION['lastname'] = $session_user['lastname'];
    echo $_SESSION['firstname']; // doesn't print anything

    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
    $_SESSION['success'] = true;

    header('location: index.php');
}
```

The MYSQL database however shows that the data is there, and the column name is indeed correct, order being: id, username, firstname, lastname, email, password.

I am lost, what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: `session_user = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);` should be `session_user = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results);` (note the `s` on `results`)

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input, especially that which comes from the client side. Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: **Never store passwords in clear text or using MD5/SHA1!** Only store password hashes. Use PHP's [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [`password_verify()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) . If you're running a PHP version lower than 5.5 (which I really hope you aren't), you can use the [password_compat](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat) library to get the same functionality.

Comment: Always `exit()` after `header('Location: ...');`

Comment: @Dharman, thank you! All of these comments were really helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling a wrong variable `$result` instead of `$results` in your `mysqli_fetch_assoc` function.

Comment: Omg, I am an idiot. I just wasted so much time on this. Thank you so much! I was very hesitant on asking this question, apologies that it wasn't a deserving question.

Comment: @Blizzard it wasn't. Especially because you were *supposed to be informed of the problem*. PHP actually throws an error when you try to access a non-existent variable but for some reason it didn't appear on your screen. Please check my article on [how to configure php error reporting properly](https://phpdelusions.net/articles/error_reporting) and then make sure you can see every error occurred.

Answer (score -2):

may be this will work.

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($results) > 0) {
    $session_user = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

    $_SESSION['firstname'] = $session_user['firstname'];
    $_SESSION['lastname'] = $session_user['lastname'];
    echo $_SESSION['firstname']; // doesn't print anything

    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
    $_SESSION['success'] = true;

    header('location: index.php');
}
```